# Scan remote directory and find sequential images with known constants

Tags: search, directory, find

I have a quick and dirty project I need assistance with.

Outline: A remote server uses randomized file naming for storing JPEGs. All of the JPEGs are stored within the same directory. For example, "website.com/photos/". All of the images in that directory have a 10-digit (0-9) file name, with the suffix .jpg. The images are sequentially named (for example 12XXXXXXXX.jpg then much later the series becomes 13XXXXXXXX.jpg) but not every sequential number is used. Most are not. One image might be 1300055000.jpg but then the next image won't be until 130099000.jpg.

I am looking for a program to scan this directory and 'try' every file name possibility (0000000000.jpg - 9999999999.jpg) and then output a URL sheet (basic HTML) with links to the working JPEGs that are found.

All non-working JPEGs when tried return a 404 not found page. All working JPEGs return a sizable photo.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated! I'd be willing to compensate for the work. Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying you have direct access to the remote directory (via a share, for example) or do you only have access through a URL? What operating system are you using: Linux or Windows?

Comment: Windows or Apple OS X OS and while we do have direct access via a share, for this project, we are only allowed to access via URL. Thank you rghome!

Comment: Please let me know if anyone can provide assistance with this. Thank you.

Comment: Your numbers have 10 digits, so if each request took 10ms, then i t would take 3 years to try all of the combinations. So you are going to have to think of another solution (e.g., access the share or allow directory access to the folder).